# Is it possible to manually execute a single systemd timer-paired service unit for testing purposes?

Tags: systemd

I have a timer/service unit-set that should run once a day under `--user` conditions.  It shows up with `systemctl --user status` and gets logged in journal but there is a part of the command that fails.

It seems that something in the command is not being interpreted correctly.  I want to futz with the unit file and run the service, examine the log, etc to debug the issue; however editing the timer to trigger a minute in the future, waiting, and checking the log is... tedious.

Can do something like `systemctl --user execute xxxxxx.service` to just run the dang thing as if the timer triggered?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can activate any unit manually, unless it contains a `RefuseManualStart=yes` and/or `RefuseManualStop=yes` directive (which do exactly what they say). Just issue `systemctl --user start <whatever>` (and `systemctl --user stop <whatever>` to do the opposite).

To quote [systemctl(1)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#start%20PATTERN...):

> **start** *PATTERN...*
>
> Start (activate) one or more units specified on the command line.
>
> <...>
>
> **stop** *PATTERN...*
>
> Stop (deactivate) one or more units specified on the command line.

---

Note that manually starting the timer's paired unit does not affect the timer's own state (i. e. it won't change the timer's `LastTrigger*` or `NextElapse*` properties) and does not change the time it will next elapse. Forcibly elapsing a timer is not supported in systemd.

Comment: Not working here: `Failed to restart {foo}.service: Operation refused, unit {foo}.service may be requested by dependency only.`

Comment: @eMPee584 Since this answer was written, systemd gained new directives `RefuseManualStart=` and `RefuseManualStop=` (which do exactly what they say). I've updated my answer to mention that.

Comment: I tried this on the fstrim.timer. But for the timer it doesn't do anything. (enables it I think) When issued on fstrim.service, probably something happened. Is there no way to trigger the timer so it shows it was actually executed?

Comment: @JPT "starting" a timer means that the timer starts ticking. Forcibly elapsing a timer is not supported in systemd. If you need this, just start the paired unit directly (in your case, `fstrim.service`).

Comment: So no, there is no way to manually trigger a timer. You may want to work that information into the answer, since it's what is actually answering the question.

Comment: Doesn't work: even though the command succeeds, doing a `systemctl --user status foo.timer` says `Active: … 18min ago`. And the time in logs says similarly `Apr 06 15:15:26 … Started run my script.` whereas the current time is ≈15:30.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Yes, manually starting the paired unit does not do anything to the timer's own state. As said above, forcibly elapsing a timer is not supported in systemd. I have clarified this in the answer now.