# Force systemd timer to run immediately?

Tags: systemd

I'm writing a service with a timer and got wrong `WorkingDirectory` in the `.service` file. Timer runs as expected. How I can force run for the service's timer now that I've revisited the `.service` file?

I've tried:

```
$ systemctl --user enable $(pwd)/mycollector.service
$ systemctl --user start mycollector.timer
$ systemctl --user reload mycollector.timer
```

and

```
$ systemd-run --user mycollector.timer
```

But it's still waiting:

```
$ systemctl --user list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT       LAST PASSED UNIT              ACTIVATES
Thu 2019-06-20 23:53:28 UTC  43min left n/a  n/a    mycollector.timer mycollector.service
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to manually execute a single systemd timer-paired service unit for testing purposes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206637/is-it-possible-to-manually-execute-a-single-systemd-timer-paired-service-unit-fo)

Answer (score 17):

I don’t think you can force the timer to stop waiting and fire immediately, short of changing its calendar definition; but you can force the corresponding service to run:

```
systemctl --user start mycollector.service
```

The timer will fire as scheduled, later on.

Comment: Not working here: `Failed to restart {foo}.service: Operation refused, unit {foo}.service may be requested by dependency only.`

Comment: @eMPee584 that’s presumably because your service is configured to refuse manual stops/starts ([`RefuseManualStart`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#RefuseManualStart=)). Please ask a new question is you want more help.

Comment: thanks for the hint; actually it's `RefuseManualStart=no RefuseManualStop=yes`.. and for whatever reason, manual invocation is working now.. ah well `: )`